# Problems setting colnames in R (creates numbers random numbers)

Tags: r, excel, melt

Data can be found here : http://www.scb.se/hitta-statistik/statistik-efter-amne/befolkning/befolkningens-sammansattning/befolkningsstatistik/pong/tabell-och-diagram/helarsstatistik--kommun-lan-och-riket2/folkmangd-i-lan-17492015/

```
library(readxl)
scb <- read_excel(file.choose()) 
scb <- scb[3:34,1:56] # Remove data that is not needed
scbnew <- data.frame(t(scb))

colnames(scbnew) <- scbnew[1,] # Nope
colnames(scbew) <- as.character(scbnew[1,]) # Nope
```

Instead I get colnames with numbers mainly the number 56. My objective is to have the columns as rows and vice versa. Did not work in gather/reshape/melt for me, if someone wants to show how (no code from me sorry)

Dput

```
structure(list(c("Folkmängden länsvis 1749 - 2015", NA, "Län", 
"Stockholm2", "Uppsala3", "Södermanland", "Östergötland", 
"Jönköping4", "Kronoberg", "Kalmar", "Gotland", "Blekinge", 
"Skåne5", "Halland", "Västra Götaland4", "Värmland", "Örebro", 
"Västmanland3", "Dalarna6", "Gävleborg", "Västernorrland", 
"Jämtland", "Västerbotten", "Norrbotten", "Stockholms stad2", 
"Kristianstad5", "Malmöhus5", "Göteborgs och Bohus4", "Älvsborg4", 
"Skaraborg4", "Värmland och Örebro", "Gävleborg, Västernorrland och Jämtland", 
"Västernorrland och Jämtland", "Västerbotten och Norrbotten", 
"Ej fördelat", "Riket", NA, NA, "1 Avser folkmängden den 31 december enligt indelningen vid samma tidpunkt, utom för åren 1910 - 1930, 1940 - 1945 samt 1955 - 2010 där indelningen avser den 1 januari följande år samt för år 1950 där indelningen avser den 1 januari 1952. ", 
"2 Stockholms stad uppgick i Stockholms län den 1 januari 1968.", 
"3 Heby kommun bytte län från Västmanland till Uppsala 1 januari 2007.", 
"4 Göteborgs och Bohus län, Älvsborgs län och Skaraborgs län bildade Västra Götalands län 1 januari 1998 (exkl. Habo och Mullsjö kommuner som tillfördes Jönköpings län).", 
"5 Kristianstads län och Malmöhus län bildade Skåne län 1 januari 1997.", 
"6 Namnändrades från Kopparbergs län 1 januari 1997.", NA, 
"Källa: 1749-1950 Historisk statistik för \r\n           Sverige, Del 1. Befolkning", 
"          1955, 1960 Befolkningsrörelsen, År \r\n          1955, 1960", 
"          1965 Folkmängdens förändringar, \r\n          1965", 
"          1970-2015 Statistikdatabasen (SCB)", NA), c(NA, "År1", 
"1749", "86085", "62804", "76182", "123193", "85268", "65290", 
"92520", "23902", "28241", ".", "56068", ".", ".", ".", "70503", 
"93982", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "55464", "90615", "105578", 
"75959", "124119", "97118", "168154", "108282", ".", "34406", 
"40991", "1764724", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1750", "89600", "62900", "78595", "127710", 
"103753", "66200", "89100", "24122", "34717", ".", "57533", ".", 
".", ".", "70600", "96701", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "53502", 
"90550", "105900", "80375", "126463", "109400", "171800", "110300", 
".", "35900", "-5043", "1780678", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1751", "91399", "63895", 
"79817", "128911", "106317", "67283", "96053", "24562", "35694", 
".", "58234", ".", ".", ".", "71952", "97428", ".", ".", ".", 
".", ".", "55700", "90335", "105163", "76537", "115853", "97918", 
"173917", "111890", ".", "36869", "16405", "1802132", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1754", 
"93359", "64330", "81828", "131456", "108529", "69117", "100461", 
"25298", "38392", ".", "60258", ".", ".", ".", "69677", "100761", 
".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "61766", "92205", "109401", "78264", 
"116007", "102052", "181188", "114914", ".", "38051", "19733", 
"1857047", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), c(NA, NA, "1757", "92886", "64763", "81570", "130865", "110671", 
"70050", "101325", "26940", "39237", ".", "61332", ".", ".", 
".", "72400", "102121", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "71863", "93039", 
"109263", "80427", "118977", "103068", "180435", "118140", ".", 
"41000", "22618", "1892990", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1760", "93599", "66176", 
"81779", "133494", "112813", "70867", "104762", "25442", "39612", 
".", "62459", ".", ".", ".", "72892", "104692", ".", ".", ".", 
".", ".", "69211", "93770", "108390", "81113", "120383", "106434", 
"184164", "119739", ".", "41457", "32000", "1925248", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1763", 
"93237", "67664", "82837", "135562", "114957", "72381", "107000", 
"26491", "40459", ".", "62752", ".", ".", ".", "74237", "106345", 
"63036", ".", ".", ".", ".", "72989", "97927", "113296", "84358", 
"119723", "110581", "188418", ".", "62089", "43672", "12227", 
"1952238", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), c(NA, NA, "1766", "95103", "69260", "84257", "138690", "116338", 
"73708", "110747", "26986", "41149", ".", "65244", ".", ".", 
".", "76321", "108353", "65305", ".", ".", ".", ".", "68936", 
"99660", "115195", "88097", "124937", "111776", "194425", ".", 
"63976", "43137", "10542", "1992142", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1769", "97683", "70143", 
"85326", "140008", "115926", "75935", "114926", "27747", "41839", 
".", "65865", ".", ".", ".", "76669", "109925", "66936", ".", 
".", ".", ".", "68745", "102369", "117461", "89429", "129037", 
"112862", "196405", ".", "65501", "44390", "15364", "2030491", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1772", "98631", "70283", "86581", "141327", "115560", "74219", 
"116424", "27987", "54252", ".", "65973", ".", ".", ".", "76667", 
"110484", "68165", ".", ".", ".", ".", "72444", "99864", "115861", 
"88105", "126525", "110365", "193776", ".", "67359", "44185", 
"7198", "2032235", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1795", "92776", "78413", "94424", "155012", 
"113328", "85767", "129647", "30012", "59993", ".", "69668", 
".", "130097", "94587", "80851", "119088", "81227", ".", ".", 
".", ".", "75191", "113264", "136776", "110563", "148144", "134939", 
".", ".", "79480", "67890", "-", "2281137", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1800", "96280", 
"81131", "96547", "158057", "114480", "87604", "129548", "31291", 
"62402", ".", "71599", ".", "135438", "95025", "86583", "122624", 
"83260", ".", ".", ".", ".", "75517", "116681", "142056", "116674", 
"152937", "135697", ".", ".", "84500", "71372", "-", "2347303", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
"År1", "1805", "99377", "84141", "98761", "162859", "117381", 
"89631", "136296", "32988", "67200", ".", "73594", ".", "140100", 
"100428", "84808", "124816", "84799", "59684", "31819", "33872", 
"34017", "72652", "120547", "149892", "118429", "156271", "138410", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "9267", "2422039", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1810", "96688", "80577", 
"98663", "163320", "116131", "89977", "138421", "32607", "69195", 
".", "73686", ".", "134808", "95236", "82201", "118652", "83594", 
"60500", "33179", "33733", "32402", "65474", "120511", "153824", 
"116620", "152363", "135489", ".", ".", ".", ".", "18500", "2396351", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1815", "97345", "80099", "99590", "163831", "117562", "91880", 
"140820", "33380", "72967", ".", "77266", ".", "140977", "96784", 
"83814", "119648", "88123", "63123", "35015", "36706", "34132", 
"72989", "126119", "165432", "125622", "159664", "142178", ".", 
".", ".", ".", "-", "2465066", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1820", "97704", "80216", 
"101291", "172546", "121554", "96019", "149901", "35564", "78951", 
".", "80093", ".", "148260", "100459", "85635", "122840", "91761", 
"67087", "36894", "40364", "37142", "75569", "134683", "176637", 
"134919", "170070", "148531", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "2584690", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1825", "103095", "81897", "106793", "182280", "129996", 
"102709", "160720", "38151", "85314", ".", "85657", ".", "163372", 
"109254", "88618", "129388", "96736", "72237", "39122", "44911", 
"40624", "79473", "145380", "192199", "146691", "187021", "159614", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "2771252", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1830", "104090", "81742", 
"108327", "187609", "137478", "108741", "165743", "38954", "85734", 
".", "88975", ".", "172858", "116255", "89262", "134820", "102736", 
"78421", "42225", "49994", "43887", "80621", "150372", "200103", 
"154054", "197697", "167384", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "2888082", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1835", "108098", "84777", "111833", "197045", "144853", 
"114156", "174011", "40671", "90801", ".", "93355", ".", "186783", 
"121530", "91461", "139538", "107250", "83920", "44239", "53144", 
"45356", "82655", "157933", "209584", "157012", "210259", "175175", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "3025439", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1840", "110279", "85294", 
"114920", "206625", "150477", "121454", "184557", "41575", "95807", 
".", "94934", ".", "195546", "125061", "92494", "138141", "109797", 
"85875", "45769", "54603", "49328", "84161", "165880", "221670", 
"164974", "218618", "181048", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "3138887", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1845", "113310", "87700", "118664", "214628", "156988", 
"129186", "196116", "43268", "102342", ".", "100419", ".", "209596", 
"131722", "94850", "145333", "116175", "93775", "49077", "60815", 
"53429", "88242", "177767", "234207", "176696", "233125", "189106", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "3316536", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1850", "114643", "89323", 
"120113", "222484", "163426", "136623", "202178", "44572", "107827", 
".", "105726", ".", "221885", "137660", "96691", "151497", "120158", 
"99558", "52271", "67674", "58835", "93070", "189627", "253084", 
"187583", "246136", "199897", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "3482541", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1855", "118056", "90877", "123684", "231358", "166591", 
"143707", "212432", "46985", "111255", ".", "110815", ".", "232521", 
"142863", "98879", "158755", "126368", "107631", "56127", "75974", 
"63649", "97952", "196206", "268579", "196662", "254290", "208795", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "3641011", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1860", "121737", "92536", 
"126705", "240917", "171011", "152225", "221029", "50137", "117875", 
".", "119578", ".", "247171", "151651", "103300", "166899", "136061", 
"116669", "61218", "81478", "69225", "112391", "209581", "284430", 
"214342", "269322", "222240", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "3859728", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
"År1", "1865", "128458", "96766", "133900", "253148", "183851", 
"162553", "233165", "53165", "125436", ".", "126060", ".", "259612", 
"162717", "108859", "174758", "143793", "127524", "68071", "88763", 
"74576", "133361", "222235", "305261", "232181", "279153", "236775", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4114141", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1870", "131244", "100519", 
"136114", "254265", "179873", "158879", "233110", "54028", "126037", 
".", "127221", ".", "260392", "167796", "114033", "175523", "147416", 
"134598", "70463", "91759", "76057", "136016", "221957", "316042", 
"232389", "279233", "243561", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4168525", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1875", "136582", "104371", "140922", "264689", "188665", 
"165531", "239847", "54649", "131812", ".", "131710", ".", "267081", 
"178951", "123057", "186612", "163197", "150234", "75756", "98043", 
"83356", "152582", "229176", "333924", "244010", "285810", "252724", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4383291", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1880", "147021", "111019", 
"147186", "267133", "196271", "169736", "245105", "54668", "137477", 
".", "135299", ".", "268417", "182263", "128491", "190133", "178728", 
"169195", "83623", "106435", "90761", "168775", "230619", "349310", 
"261114", "288947", "257942", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4565668", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1885", "148841", "116406", "150032", "267842", "197392", 
"166881", "240507", "52570", "140071", ".", "136973", ".", "259958", 
"182513", "132056", "194291", "191223", "184884", "93091", "113541", 
"96241", "215688", "226787", "358178", "281001", "282335", "253467", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4682769", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1890", "152715", "121091", 
"154991", "266619", "193704", "160835", "232847", "51337", "142602", 
".", "136106", ".", "253326", "182557", "137453", "197449", "206924", 
"208763", "100455", "122784", "104783", "246454", "221691", "368817", 
"297824", "275780", "247074", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4784981", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1895", "157457", "123015", "161722", "270973", "195856", 
"158838", "229176", "51855", "143387", ".", "139356", ".", "252915", 
"188771", "142735", "206774", "218864", "217220", "104259", "133336", 
"115500", "271638", "219858", "383203", "313340", "274698", "244514", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "4919260", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1900", "172852", "123863", 
"167428", "279449", "203036", "159124", "227625", "52781", "146302", 
".", "141688", ".", "254284", "194924", "148271", "217708", "238048", 
"232311", "111391", "143735", "134769", "300624", "219166", "409304", 
"337175", "279514", "241069", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "5136441", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1905", "192328", "125610", "169576", "287421", "206177", 
"157555", "226876", "53399", "148755", ".", "143448", ".", "255142", 
"200087", "149050", "223893", "246153", "240873", "113229", "152746", 
"150220", "324488", "220104", "430955", "357120", "280360", "239320", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "5294885", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1910", "229181", "128171", 
"178568", "294179", "214454", "157965", "228129", "55217", "149359", 
".", "147224", ".", "260135", "207021", "155920", "233873", "253792", 
"250512", "118115", "161366", "161132", "342323", "228307", "457214", 
"381270", "287692", "241284", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "5522403", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1915", "228230", "132400", "183839", "300165", "219895", 
"156596", "227622", "55451", "150055", ".", "147296", ".", "260447", 
"212113", "162774", "242349", "260586", "259826", "124541", "170299", 
"174227", "392427", "234994", "475893", "406112", "293577", "241026", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "5712740", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1920", "243194", "136718", 
"190478", "305742", "227629", "158612", "231077", "55853", "147098", 
".", "148712", ".", "268681", "218506", "168815", "254259", "268300", 
"265227", "133536", "182246", "182953", "419440", "241018", "487459", 
"424788", "300371", "243777", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "5904489", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
"År1", "1925", "262003", "139954", "192055", "310231", "231366", 
"158103", "231178", "56981", "148303", ".", "149716", ".", "270467", 
"222503", "165005", "253892", "277671", "273220", "136300", "195729", 
"190940", "442528", "244747", "501769", "442841", "309906", "246154", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "6053562", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1930", "265079", "138201", 
"189192", "309911", "231536", "155551", "231410", "57458", "144879", 
".", "150285", ".", "269998", "219208", "161723", "249717", "279716", 
"278562", "134514", "204031", "199826", "502213", "245928", "510607", 
"457010", "313311", "242325", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "6142191", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1935", "271284", "139155", "188862", "312283", "236106", 
"154554", "231943", "58043", "146351", ".", "152389", ".", "273293", 
"218950", "161999", "248940", "281143", "282103", "136407", "215011", 
"207694", "534236", "248627", "518903", "469861", "321553", "240816", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "6250506", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1940", "287660", "138098", 
"192394", "316994", "241744", "151408", "228260", "58532", "144962", 
".", "151634", ".", "267731", "226428", "168989", "248559", "274018", 
"275474", "138722", "219939", "216005", "590503", "248247", "530185", 
"486197", "329366", "239383", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "6371432", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1945", "321989", "146415", "201051", "332946", "253794", 
"153572", "231336", "59505", "146908", ".", "155257", ".", "272275", 
"235989", "183346", "253507", "275436", "278707", "143213", "228135", 
"229568", "671284", "253277", "551610", "510896", "338996", "244737", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "6673749", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1950", "356874", "154660", 
"214012", "347537", "271443", "157638", "236774", "58995", "146090", 
".", "163455", ".", "281396", "246950", "203553", "267081", "284934", 
"283750", "144063", "231750", "241489", "744143", "258734", "582333", 
"556799", "358988", "248388", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "7041829", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1955", "397127", "161383", "220946", "355344", "279753", 
"159482", "237256", "56927", "145387", ".", "166433", ".", "288580", 
"256174", "218393", "279041", "292541", "289365", "144393", "238277", 
"251031", "785945", "259047", "601974", "588055", "368068", "249190", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "7290112", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1960", "462720", "167722", 
"227807", "357601", "285348", "158867", "235612", "54196", "144466", 
".", "169995", ".", "291074", "262321", "232973", "286047", "293246", 
"285676", "139799", "239619", "261802", "808294", "256395", "626086", 
"625670", "374683", "249948", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "7497967", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1965", "593418", "184701", "240806", "365754", "296119", 
"164288", "235598", "53682", "149482", ".", "179905", ".", "287097", 
"267850", "249883", "281923", "292652", "277467", "130848", "233597", 
"259579", "788503", "261759", "667164", "665728", "389843", "254860", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "7772506", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1970", "1478012", "217730", 
"248413", "382674", "306648", "166736", "241026", "53723", "153585", 
".", "193108", ".", "284688", "276798", "260293", "277057", "293458", 
"273456", "125243", "233134", "255369", ".", "264170", "719597", 
"715287", "403710", "257301", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8081216", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1975", "1493546", "230028", "251913", "387088", "301986", 
"169438", "240724", "54400", "155336", ".", "219780", ".", "284249", 
"273923", "259921", "281109", "294412", "268034", "133433", "236397", 
"264386", ".", "272014", "740069", "715012", "418026", "263218", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8208442", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1980", "1528200", "243585", 
"252536", "392789", "303156", "173691", "241581", "55346", "153542", 
".", "230924", ".", "284070", "274356", "259538", "286968", "294020", 
"267935", "134934", "243856", "267054", ".", "280193", "743286", 
"711195", "425452", "269730", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8317937", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
"År1", "1985", "1578299", "251852", "249701", "393585", "300753", 
"173972", "238176", "56144", "150959", ".", "240063", ".", "279183", 
"270211", "254761", "283880", "289153", "262314", "134190", "245255", 
"262300", ".", "280354", "750140", "715728", "426698", "270468", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8358139", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "1990", "1641669", "268835", 
"255636", "403011", "308290", "177882", "241102", "57108", "150564", 
".", "254725", ".", "283110", "272513", "258487", "289067", "289294", 
"261155", "135726", "251968", "263735", ".", "289278", "779309", 
"739945", "441391", "276830", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8590630", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "1995", "1725756", "288475", "258700", "416443", "312686", 
"180377", "243372", "58120", "152737", ".", "269338", ".", "284011", 
"276417", "261101", "289956", "288509", "258290", "135584", "260472", 
"266011", ".", "294709", "817022", "770375", "449524", "279511", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8837496", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "2000", "1823210", "294196", 
"256033", "411345", "311180", "176639", "235391", "57313", "150392", 
"1129424", "275004", "1511290", "275003", "273615", "256889", 
"278259", "279262", "246903", "129566", "255640", "256238", ".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "8882792", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
NA, "2005", "1889945", "304367", "261895", "416303", "330179", 
"178443", "233944", "57488", "150696", "1169464", "285868", "1528455", 
"273288", "274121", "261391", "275755", "275994", "243736", "127028", 
"257652", "251740", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
".", "-", "9047752", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "2010", "2054343", "322500", "270738", 
"429642", "336866", "183940", "233536", "57269", "153227", "1243329", 
"299484", "1580297", "273265", "280230", "266138", "277047", 
"276508", "242625", "126691", "259286", "248609", ".", ".", ".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "-", "9415570", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, "2015", 
"2231439", "354164", "283712", "445661", "347837", "191369", 
"237679", "57391", "156253", "1303627", "314784", "1648682", 
"275904", "291012", "264276", "281028", "281815", "243897", "127376", 
"263378", "249733", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
".", "-", "9851017", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .Names = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""))
```

Comment: looking for transpose ? `t()` ?

Comment: Dont really understand,  yes I used tranpose (line 4) but I get problem with the colnames.

Comment: share a reproducible sample data here... can't work without that

Comment: I have included the original data set which an be downloaded, cant create a reproducible data as I dont know where the error is originating from.

Comment: just share the `dput(df)` once you have loaded in your session. So that we don't have to follow a long process.

Comment: Thanks for learning me dput!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `scbnew[1,]` is a data frame and not a vector. You can resolve your problem by converting `scbnew[1,]` to a vector. And that you can do by using `t(scbnew[1,])`. This is working perfectly fine for me

```
x<- t(scbnew[1,])
colnames(scbnew)<- x
```